# Router export failing while exporting multiple functions (TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function)

Tags: express, middleware, router

I'm having this odd error and I'm not knowing what to do to make it work. The thing is, I need to export some functions and express router. The thing is, if I try to set

> module.exports = {router, function1, function2}

it gaves me that error

> (TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function).

If I try to set my functions with exports.function1 = async function function1 (req,res) {blablabla} they get exported but I still get the same error... I need to use the functions in this way

```
router.get('/api/auth0/users', async (req, res,next) => {
  function1(res, next)
})
```

and I'm lacking ideas... and have no clue of why the multiple module.exports it's not working since I've used it a lot (seems like the problem is with the router.... (NOTE: I've just used an example code since mine is a 140 lines src)
(NOTE2: function1 and function2 are async since they make queries to MongoDB)

UPDATE: (Adding the import codes)
I import it in my main .js file like this

> const {router} = require('./auth/auth0')

then tell app to use it like this

> app.use(router);

app is defined using this lines

> const express = require("express");

> const app = express();

changing the export/import name to another like authRouter or something makes no difference.

Heres the complete code:

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const express = require('express')
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session')

const {generateJwt} = require("../helpers/generateJwt");
const usuarios = require('../models/usuarios')

let OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-openidconnect');

passport.serializeUser(function (user, cb) {
  cb(null, user);
});
 
passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, cb) {
  cb(null, obj);
});

passport.use(new OpenIDConnectStrategy({
issuer: 'https://' + process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/',
authorizationURL: 'https://' + process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/authorize',
tokenURL: 'https://' + process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/oauth/token',
userInfoURL: 'https://' + process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN + '/userinfo',
clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
callbackURL: '/login/callback',
scope: [ 'profile', 'email' ]
},
function verify(issuer, profile, cb) {
  if(profile){
      userEmail = profile.emails[0].value
      userProfile = profile
      whoIs = profile.id
    }
    return cb(null,profile)
    }
));


router.use(express.json())
router.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat~troubles', secured:true, key: 'sid', saveUninitialized: true, resave: false}));
router.use(passport.initialize())
router.use(passport.session())



var userProfile = ""
let userEmail = ""
let whoIs = ""
let token = ""

async function createUser(res,next) {
  try {
      token = await generateJwt(whoIs, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);
      const nAccount = new usuarios({ 
        nombre: userProfile.name.givenName,
        apellido: userProfile.name.familyName,
        auth0Id: whoIs,
        email: userEmail,
        token: token
      });
      await nAccount.save()
      return res.status(201).json({Status: "Cuenta creada exitosamente", token: token});   
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    return res.redirect('/api/auth0/logged')
  } 
}

async function findUser(res, next){
  try{
      let email = userEmail
      let mailEncontrado = await usuarios.findOne( {email} )
      if (!mailEncontrado ){
        return res.redirect('/api/auth0/register')
      }
      else {
        token = await generateJwt(whoIs, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY);
        let userID = await usuarios.findOneAndUpdate(
          {email},
          { nombreAuth0: userProfile.name.givenName,
            apellidoAuth0: userProfile.name.familyName,
            auth0Id: whoIs, 
            token: token},
          { new: true }
        )
        return res.redirect('/api/auth0/logged')
      }
      
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
    }    
}

async function userAuthenticated(res, next) {
    if( req.isAuthenticated() === true){
      console.log(req.isAuthenticated())
      return true
    } else{
      console.log(req.isAuthenticated())
      return false
    }

}

router.get('/api/auth0/login', passport.authenticate('openidconnect',{prompt: 'login', failureMessage: true}));

router.get('/api/auth0/users', async (req, res,next) => {
  findUser(res, next)
})

router.get('/api/auth0/register', async (req, res,next) => {
  createUser(res, next)
})

router.get('/login/callback', passport.authenticate('openidconnect', {
  successRedirect: '/api/auth0/users',
  failureRedirect: '/api/auth0/login'
}));


router.get('/api/auth0/logged', (req, res) => {
    if(whoIs === ""){
      return res.status(401).json('Error de autenticacion')
    }
    else {
      console.log(whoIs)
      return res.status(201).json({Status: 'Usuario logueado. ID = '+ whoIs, Token: token, Email: userEmail})
    }
})

router.get('/api/auth0/logout', (req, res) => {
    if(!req.user){
      res.json("No hay usuario autenticado")
    }
    req.logout()
    res.status(201).json("Sesion finalizada exitosamente.")
})
module.exports = {router, userAuthenticated}
```

Comment: Show us how do you import it

Comment: It's really hard to see the full picture like these smaller fragments. Try to paste em all. 140 lines are not that long. ANd use code snippet maybe would be more readable.

Comment: @n1md7 ok... that's it. The main app is 109 lines... if you need it let me know. The function I need to export is userAuthenticated. It's not finished yet, but you can see where I'm aiming at... The real problem for me is that I'm not being able to get the auth0 user data to another files where I need to. I'm bypassing it by just using the user token signed with auth0id and then getting the data from the user from the db.